# Change Action of Checkbox to Get Instead of Post

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-3.5, postback

We have an ASP.Net page that uses a checkbox to toggle between a list view and a tree view.

The problem is that this triggers a post. When we then click on one of the documents in the list, then press back in the browser, we get a page expired error.

Is it possible to change the action of the check box to trigger a get with a parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could disable the PostBack on the checkbox and use javascript (example with jQuery):

```
$('#yourcheckboxId').click(function() {
    window.location.href = '/somePage.aspx?someParam=someValue';
});
```